# Se puede mover un .jar de un zip a otro zip sin descomprimirlos?

Tags: java, jar, zip

Concretamente tengo dos archvos .war. Que al renombrarlos los puedo ver en formato zip, y quiero cambiar solo un .jar de un zip al otro, sin descomprimirlos. Hay alguna manera de hacerlo??

El jar que necesito mover es de una compilacion de otro módulo del proyecto, una dependencia.
Además, la máquina donde está el war bueno que necesito modificar es de linux, ahí es dónde necesito meter el nuevo jar sustituyendo el viejo.

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres realizar.  Trata de explicarlo mejor. ¿Queres mover un .jar dentro de un .war a otro .war?  ¿Ese .jar es de una compilación propia o un modulo externo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto!! Se puede hacer un update de un archivo del war directamente con el comando jar -uvf nombreDelWar.war /ruta/replicada/de/donde/se/encuentre/el/archivo/a/modificar/archivo.jar en mi caso. De esta forma, se actualiza el jar con el mismo nombre dentro del war.
Para que funcione hay que replicar la ruta exactamente igual a como esté dentro del war. Para que vaya al sitio correcto a modificar el archivo, porque sino te genera todo el nuevo directorio a partir del raiz.